# gnu-screen unbind key not possible

Tags: gnu-screen

I have bound a key on my screen, via screen command line and not the screenrc. Unfortunately by error I bound the key was "E", what I wanted was Ctrl-A E.

Then I was not able to type in my terminal the char "E", which is the expected behavior, screen is running my command...

What is weird, is that when I try to unbind the key by screen's command line, I am not able to insert "E", because screen is still executing the bound command.

So then, I am blocked here!? I am not able to type anymore "E", the only solution is to kill my screen session and start it again, something that I want to avoid, I have a lot of running stuffs on this session...

I have also tried to type in another editor: bindkey "E" and copy/paste it to screen's cli, it pastes every chars but "E"?

It seems to be a minor bug in screen, it should not execute bound commands when user is typing a screen command...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found a hint, I really want to share it with gnu-screen's users.

To unbind the key, I have get the octal value of my char "E", which is 105, and then I typed:

:bindkey "\105"

in the screen's command line.

This resolved my issue but I am still thinking that it is a bug in gnu-screen.

If you have another way to do it please share it. I am still interested.

Regards,